# My colleague got mad!

Tags: reverse-puzzling, retrograde-analysis

<sub>This is an entry for the [16<sup>th</sup> Fortnightly Challenge](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5509/fortnightly-topic-challenge-16-reverse-puzzling).</sub>

---

You won't believe what happened at work today! I was working on a new software when Robert,
the colleague I work with on this, got mad in a second : he banged his table, shouted the f-word
and left the office! Well, one thing I know is that he was not *really* working on the software... All the 
morning, I've seen him writing things on pieces of papers. That's why once he had left, I went to
his desk to understand his rage. Before he came back, I was able to take a glimpse at this piece of paper.

[image]

At first, I was... puzzled. But then I remembered where I had seen this grid before. I smiled.

**And you, can you find out why Robert left in anger?**

Comment: Looks a bit like a game of Minesweeper, but some of those numbers are far too big.

Comment: @randal'thor The numbers appear to be an ordering rather than relevant to potential other content/meaning in the grid

Comment: Could it really be an *n-dimensional* minesweeper, because i'd love to try it right now.

Comment: @ABcDexter It is! If you look at [the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32463433#32463433), Will has the right answer, but I'd like a more complete answer from him :-)

Comment: @IAmInPLS Ok, great. Then this is the most awesome puzzle for my return :D thanks :)

Comment: This looks like a fine place to add a [`retrograde-analysis`](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retrograde-analysis) tag. Seems that $@$Will has correctly identified a game/puzzle that fits. Is the intended answer [(mmph)](http://minefield-6d.software.informer.com/) by any chance?

Comment: @humn I'm just waiting for Will to add the grid, and explain the numbers. He has the correct answer anyway :-)

Comment: @humn Oh, feel free to add the tag, since it is *very* relevant to this problem (the numbers are indeed related to the moves).

Comment: Wouldn't square 17 and 18 have been revealed already when you click on square 1?

Comment: @Kruga Damn, you're right. I should have triple-checked :-)! I'll change the image asap.

Comment: Actually the 17 was correct since it's blocked off by a number - I believe this is [what the board looks like](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Oe3F4.png) after clicking the square marked 1.

Comment: @Will, Well, here's the image I made this puzzle from : http://i.imgur.com/otTyNk5.jpg. You can add it to your answer I think :-). (And you're right about number 17 then).

Comment: Oh whoops, actually I was mistaken and it looks like @Kruga was right - I'm gonna rollback to the previous revision.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

rand al'thor points out that

> This is a 9x9 grid like Minesweeper

and since

> the numbers 1 through 16 are present along with 8 Xs

the numbers are

> the order in which Robert clicked the squares in his Minesweeper game

but after the square marked 16, Robert's got this (image courtesy of OP)

> [image: Minesweeper endgame]

and we can now see why Robert is distressed:

> Robert is left with a 50/50 chance at winning the game (hence the ?s) since there are two mines left to find and the top right corner thus has two possible solutions:
>
> ```
> 1 2 ? ?
> X 3 ? ?
> - X 2 1
> ```
>
> could be either of these
>
> ```
> 1 2 X 2    |    1 2 2 X
> X 3 3 X    |    X 3 X 2
> - X 2 1    |    - X 2 1
> ```

... which is a situation that always frustrates *me*, though I don't get *quite* as angry...